# Why Netbean ignore PHPUnit testsuite from the XML config?

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, netbeans-6.9, test-suite

I've setup netbean to use my config.xml file, and it works well except for the testsuites part that is completly ignored by netbean.

It look like netbean try to execute this command:

phpunit -c config.xml path/to/tests/

instead of just:

```
phpunit -c config.xml
```

How can I configure netbean in order to handler the testsuites definition inside a phpunit XML configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug of netbeans, see [Bug 199072 - NetBeans ignores PHPUNIT.XML and runs tests from all folders](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199072).

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans 7.0 allows you to specify a test suite in the project's properties, but I don't see a way to tell it to use what's in the XML configuration file.

Comment: I don't want to ask netbeans to select some testsuite from the XML config. I want netbeans to handle the config.xml file, because right now netbean totally ignore the testsuites instruction (all of them). Probably because netbean pass the path to phpunit instead of runing a phpunit call inside the good folder.